# Ready made funds?

Tags: investing, index-fund, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies

I see on Interactive Investor, there are options to purchase ‘Ready-made funds’ such as European, US, UK markets.

From the website: “Each ready-made selection holds four separate funds, all of which are managed by well known and regarded fund managers who have consistently beaten their benchmark.”

Are these a good idea for a beginner? Something simple to buy and hold?

Comment: What are the fees? If they charge fees on the ready made fund and then the four funds charge fees too, these could be pretty expensive. There are some ETFs with very low fees and the fee cuts directly into your rate of return.

Answer (score 2):

What you’ve stumbled upon appear to be a “fund of funds”. It adds a layer of cost that’s best avoided. Why not just stick with your own chosen mix of the underlying funds?

Comment: Thanks for the answer (finally) Joe. Well, I have very limited knowledge, so don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Knowledge is power. Read all you can, there's a lot to learn, but it's doable. You'll see that for most investors, we tend to advise low cost index funds/ETFs.